# Handling strings in a file with differnt character encodings (ISO-8859-1 vs UTF-8)

Tags: php, utf-8, iso-8859-1

I have a set of lines in a file where each line might represent multiple lines of comments. The line separator chosen by the original developer was the pilcrow (¶) since he felt this would never show up in someone's comment. I'm now putting these into a database and wish to use a more typical line separator (although one that may be set by the application installer).

The problem is that some of the lines use the ISO-8859-1 encoding (hex b6) while others use the UTF-8 encoding (hex c2b6). I'm looking for an elegant way to deal with this that has better support than what I'm currently doing.

This is how I've handled it so far, but I'm rather looking for a more elegant solution:

```
// Due to the way the quote file is stored, line breaks can either be
// in 2-byte or 1-byte characters for the pilcrow. Since we're dealing
// with them on a unix system, it makes more sense to replace these
// funky characters with a newline character as is more standard.
//
// To do this, however, requires a bit of chicanery. We have to do
// 1-byte replacement, but with a 2-byte character.
//
// First, some constants:
define('PILCROW', '¶'); // standard two-byte pilcrow character
define('SHORT_PILCROW', chr(0XB6)); // the one-byte version used in the source data some places
define('NEEDLE', '/['.PILCROW.SHORT_PILCROW.']/'); // this is what is searched for
define('REPLACEMENT', $GLOBALS['linesep']);

function fix_line_breaks($quote)
{
  $t0 = preg_replace(NEEDLE,REPLACEMENT,$quote); // convert either long or short pilcrow to a newline. 
  return $t0;
}
```

Comment: Yuck for mixed charsets! I feel for you :-(

Comment: Why don't you read line after line and put each line in the database as UTF-8, using utf8_decode on the ISO-8859-1 lines to get them in the proper encoding ? You don't seem to need a new separator if you put each line in a different record.

Comment: @dystroy - each line of the file may contain a multi-line comment. Each line of the file itself is placed into the data base, but rather than deal with the mixed encodings on output, I'd rather make sure they go in clean on input, and preserve the multi-line aspect. The difficulty is I don't know how to tell which lines contain which separator.

Comment: OK. So I don't get what could be better than what you did, if you don't want to change the encoding.

Comment: If I understand this correctly you still need to convert any lines not in the correct encoding, right?

Comment: @mcrumley actually -- you may be right. I was considering just the use of the pilcrow causing problems, but it could have other characters like that, too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would do it like this:

```
define('PILCROW', '¶'); // standard two-byte pilcrow character
define('REPLACEMENT', $GLOBALS['linesep']);

function fix_encoding($quote) {
    return mb_convert_encoding($quote, 'UTF-8', mb_detect_encoding($quote));
}

function fix_line_breaks($quote) {
    // convert UTF-8 pilcrow to a newline.
    return str_replace(PILCROW, REPLACEMENT, $quote);
}
```

For each line comment, call `fix_encoding` then `fix_line_breaks`

```
$quote = fix_encoding($quote);
$quote = fix_line_breaks($quote);
```

Comment: Oh, I like that, thank you. I had just about come up with something similar. I figured it out going the other way, converting the UTF-8 strings, but this may be better. Interestingly, when I run `mb_detect_encoding` on the 8859 version, it returns an empty string.

Comment: Ok, slight change. mb_detect_encoding is returning FALSE, so the function need to check for that and substitute ISO-8859-1 if so. It Works!